# VBA Excel: FTP GetFile via WinINet

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

I am trying to get an FTP Download operation to work with VBA Excel (on Excel 2013 x64, Windows 7 SP1 x64). I found some code that maps to the WinInet API and I can successfully *upload* files using the `PutFile` function but I am looking to get a `GetFile` function to work as well.

To get working what I have so far, I used the following: [second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026308/how-can-i-upload-data-using-ftp-http-or-a-socket-from-a-spreadsheet-with-vba-f), and this [link](https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCodeAsText.asp?txtCodeId=6479&lngWId=1). I've been mostly using the second answer from SO to get PutFile to work. I had to make some changes to the original code to make it compatible with 32 bit and 64 bit systems.

You can see my progress [here](https://dpaste.de/4Axe).

What I am looking to do is make an easy to use Sub that calls this declaration:

```
Private Declare Function FtpGetFile Lib "WinInet" Alias "FtpGetFileA" (ByVal hFtp As Long, ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, ByVal lpszNewFile As String, ByVal fFailIfExists As Long, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long
```

I.E. a Sub like this:

```
Public Sub GetFile(RemoteFilename As String, LocalFilename As String)
    If FtpGetFile(' what arguments do I put here ') = 0 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , LastError
    End If
End Sub
```

I am struggling because I am not very familiar with the WinInet API and am having difficulty parsing the required arguments and what are the appropriate variables to pass for those arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started on the right path, based on the example provided.

In your class module:

```
Public Sub GetFile(RemoteFilename As String, NewFilename As String)
    If FtpGetFile(m_hFtp, RemoteFilename, NewFilename, False, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0) = 0 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , LastError
    End If
End Sub
```

How to call it:

```
Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim ftp As New CFtp
    ftp.Connect "serverAddress", "username", "password"
    ftp.GetFile "nameOfFileOnServer.txt", "C:\SomePath\nameOfNewFile.txt"
    ftp.Disconnect
End Sub
```

The parameters specify some attributes to associate with the downloaded file. For example, `fFailIfExists` is a `Boolean` that describes whether or not to throw an exception if it is trying to overwrite a local file that already exists. The other flags specify attributes to attach to the file it creates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When trying that, I get "Run-time error '-2147221503 (80040001)'"

Comment: @tsurantino: At which line? Use the debugger to step through the call (click 'debug', then step through it by using the F8 key). Are you able to connect successfully? Are you sure that the exact filename exists in the home folder of your FTP? Finally, are you sure that you have the correct user permissions to save in the local folder specified? Try using the full path of your desktop if you're not sure (`C:\Users\tsurantino\Desktop\NewFile`).

Comment: Wow so the error was not specifying a full path for downloading it seems. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me debug it. I tried providing C:\filename.txt but it seems like the C:\ drive was protected.