# Cannot get files from ftp using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, ftp, wininet

I want to download an image from ftp to use it later in a access report, the problem is the ftpgetFile returning 0 and not downloading the image in the folder.

```
Public Function RecuperarFirmaMuestreadores(userID As Long)
Dim firma As String
Dim id As String
id = CStr(userID) & ".jpg"
sign = ftpfirma("XXX.XX.XXX.XXX", "User", "password", "/document/", id)
End Function



Function ftpfirma(ByVal HostName As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String, ByVal sDir As String, id As String) As String



Dim sOrgPAth As String
Dim pData As WIN32_FIND_DATA
Dim hFind As Long, lRet As Long
Dim hConnection, hOpen, hFile  As Long
Dim sFiles() As String
Dim firma As Long

sPath = String(MAX_PATH, 0)


hOpen = InternetOpen("FTPGET", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 1)
hConn = InternetConnect(hOpen, HostName, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, Username, Password, 1, 0, 2)

' Change Directory
Call FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hConn, sDir)

' get list of directory
Call FtpGetCurrentDirectory(hConn, sPath, Len(sPath))

Call FTPGetFile(hConn, id, "C:\Documents and Settings\Adrian\Mis documentos\Descargas", True, 0, 0 Or GENERIC_READ, 0)

' Close Internet Connection
Call InternetCloseHandle(hOpen)
Call InternetCloseHandle(hConn)


End Function
```

In the ftp the image exists and it's in /documents with a name like 123.jpg, and I'm downloading into my downloads folder and I don't get errors to work with.

Thank you in advance.

*EDIT*

I try what you say but it's not working, and getLastError return 0

```
Call FTPGetFile(hConn, id, "C:\Documents and Settings\Adrian\Mis documentos\Descargas\" & id, True, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0)
e = getLastError()
```

*SOLUTION GIVEN BY MARTIN*

Make sure the flag value isn't 0 like this case and is INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE

```
 hConn = InternetConnect(hOpen, HostName, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, Username, Password, 1, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 2)
```

Thank you so much to all for your answers.

Comment: What does `GetLastError` return after `FtpGetFile` call?

Comment: You miss the backslash: `.. \Descargas\" & id, ..`.

Comment: Look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455437/vba-excel-ftp-getfile-via-wininet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third `lpszNewFile` argument of [`FtpGetFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-ftpgetfilea) is a path to a file, not a directory.

So it should be like:

```vb
Call FTPGetFile(hConn, id, "C:\Documents and Settings\Adrian\Mis documentos\Descargas\" & id, ...)
```

---

Also, in general, you should use [`INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/api-flags#INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE) with `InternetConnect`.

Without the flag, the `InternetConnect` defaults to the active mode, which is mostly unusable, when a firewall or a NAT is involved.

Comment: Which of my two suggestions did help?

Comment: Both of them, but the cause of this problem was because de INTERNET_FLAG_ PASSIVE

Answer (score 0):

We use this variation successfully:

```vb
Private Const FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN     As Long = 0
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD          As Long = &H80000000

<snip>

    If FtpGetFileA(hConn, strRemoteFile, strLocalFile, 1, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN Or INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0) Then
        Debug.Print "done"
    Else
        Debug.Print "fail"
    End If
```

Comment: Why do you think that `INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD` will make any difference?

Comment: It works here and is different from what the questioneer uses - and is easy to test.